# Set value of Password field on UIWebView load?

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview

html line: `<input title="Enter your User-ID" class="acctAccessInput4" name="username" id="maskedusername" type="password" value=""></label>`

How can i automatically fill in the field once the UIWebView loads?

this does not work: `[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('maskedusername').value = 'myPassword'"];`

Comment: It usually a good start to define "does not work" .. also, I *suspect* this is caused because it's a **password** field (which often has restrictions on the value access for security concerns).

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not work, because the page is not fully loaded.

try:

implements the delegate and add the following code.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('maskedusername').value = 'myPassword'"];    
}
```

The following code is executed on page load.

Answer (score 0):

Try loading it initially in the HTML string itself:

```
<input title="Enter your User-ID" class="acctAccessInput4" name="username" id="maskedusername" type="password" value="pasword"></label>
```